# I am trying to copy an object with particle system animation but not working

Tags: animation, particles, particle-nodes

I am trying to copy an object with particle system animation into another blend file. Every time I copy it, it moves without the particle system.

Note: If I apply the particle mesh, it doesn't keep the animation.

Here is blend file https://blend-exchange.com/b/5PYZ6z02

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use `File>Append` instead? Appending the object and then the particle system should make it work.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka I have never tried to append. I am trying it now for the first time. It's not working. so either I'm doing the wrong thing or it's just not working.

Comment: The append doesn't work too? Ok. I'll check your blend file and come back when I am done.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Okay. Thank you.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka. Thank you so much. that's actually got the case. I got the blend file from a site and was trying to insert it but nothing was happening. Thank yu. It now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look into your file and I think you may just have copied the wrong object. The thing is you have 3 meshes objects in your file : the `Sphere`, the `Wave` (which serves as a rendered mesh for the particles) and a `Cube`.

[image]

That `Cube` is actually the one that has the particle system attached to :

[image]

And I don't know if it was on purpose but, the cube doesn't have any vertices (you may have gone into edit mode and deleted them), but it's origin point is still visible when we select it from the outliner :

[image]

In the screenshot above, I moved it back slightly so you can see that it's actually the one that emits the particles (not the sphere). And with the cube selected, I pressed `CTRL+C` and opened a new Blender scene, pressed `CTRL+V` and it pasted the object successfully :

[image]

Notice in the bottom of the viewport that the `Wave` object has been copied along with the emitter.

I think the first time you copied the `Sphere` alone and since no particle system is assigned to it, you only has the sphere pasted in the new Blend file.